# how to stop differential build in angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular8

Is there any options to prevent new feature of angular 8 to divide bundles for old browsers? Because it takes double time for build which is very long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the docs on [differential build/loading](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading):

> The Angular CLI handles differential loading for you as part of the
>   build process for deployment. The ng build command produces the
>   necessary bundles used for differential loading, based on your browser
>   support requirements and compilation target.
>
> The Angular CLI uses two configurations for differential loading:
>
> - Browsers list The browserslist configuration file is included in your application project structure and provides the minimum browsers
>     your application supports. See the Browserslist spec for complete
>     configuration options.
> - TypeScript configuration In the TypeScript configuration file, tsconfig.json, the target in the compilerOptions section determines
>     the ECMAScript target version that the code is compiled to. Modern
>     browsers support ES2015 natively, while ES5 is more commonly used to
>     support legacy browsers.
>
> By default, legacy browsers such as IE 9-11 are ignored, and the
>   compilation target is ES2015. As a result, this produces two builds,
>   and differential loading is enabled. If you ignore browsers without
>   ES2015 support, a single build is produced.

There is also a section to [opt out](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#opting-out-of-differential-loading):

> Opting out of differential loading
>
> Differential loading can be explicitly disabled if it causes
>   unexpected issues or you need to target ES5 specifically for legacy
>   browser support.
>
> To explicitly disable differential loading:
>
> Enable the dead or IE browsers in the browserslist config file by removing the not keyword in front of them.
>       Set the target in the compilerOptions to es5.

Comment: This seems not to be helpful with Angular 9. I still get 90+ files generated in the output directory. Any idea how to effectively prevent differential build?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply Switch back to es5 from es2015 as compilation target in your tsconfig.json.

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target":"es5",
    ...
 }
```