# Angular 8: Differential Build Not Working

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 8.3.23.

I successfully build and deploy to localhost using:
`ng serve --ssl`
but when I build for production using:
`ng build --prod`
The build works without error:
`Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading... ES5 bundle generation complete.`
When I browse to my app using any of the latest browsers (Opera, Chrome, Firefox), I get console error:
`Uncaught TypeError: e.getOwnMetadata is not a function`

I have studied the accepted answer for [Differential Build/Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736447/how-to-stop-differential-build-in-angular-8) and followed its advice to study the Angular Deployment doc's [Differential Loading](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading) section. I have verified that my tsconfig.json agrees with the doc's suggestion:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext", 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015", 
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

The Angular doc also has a link to [browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist), which has an example that I followed to add a browserslist at the bottom of my package.json file:

```
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults",
    "last 2 Opera versions",
    "last 2 Firefox versions",
    "last 2 Chrome versions",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not Edge <= 86",
    "not Safari <= 20",
    "not iOS <= 11",
    "maintained node versions"
  ]
```

The root problem is that my app will not initialize, due to the following error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: e.getOwnMetadata is not a function
    at main-es2015.d5bb5cb8e875001c3644.js:1
    at a (main-es2015.d5bb5cb8e875001c3644.js:1)
    at main-es2015.d5bb5cb8e875001c3644.js:1
    at Module.zUnb (main-es2015.d5bb5cb8e875001c3644.js:1)
    at d (runtime-es2015.25716398ef338277e502.js:1)
    at Object.0 (main-es2015.d5bb5cb8e875001c3644.js:1)
    at d (runtime-es2015.25716398ef338277e502.js:1)
    at c (runtime-es2015.25716398ef338277e502.js:1)
    at Array.a [as push] (runtime-es2015.25716398ef338277e502.js:1)
    at main-es2015.d5bb5cb8e875001c3644.js:1
```

Since the app works fine with a localhost build, the only thing I can think of causing the error is the differential build. But, how to fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at [Git Issue 7476](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7476).

Adding the following to my polyfills.ts file was all that was needed:

`import 'reflect-metadata';`